# Libxml2: undefined reference to xmlTextReaderConstName

Tags: gcc, linker, libxml2

I have installed the latest [libxml2-2.8.0](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz), as usual: `$ ./configure`,  `$ make`, `$ make install`.

The `$ xml2-config --cflags --libs` gives this output:

```
-I/usr/local/include/libxml2
-L/usr/local/lib -lxml2 -lm
```

But trying to compile any example...

```
$ gcc `xml2-config --cflags --libs` xmltest.c
```

The linker says:

```
/tmp/cc8ezrPl.o: In function `processNode':
xmltest.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstName'
xmltest.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `xmlTextReaderConstValue'

...etc.
```

Anything I've googled can be solved by `xml2-config --cflags --libs` flags, or upgrading to the latest version of libxml2, or something. Unfortunately, neither works for me.

What can be the steps to identify the problem?

Using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The libraries should be specified only after the source file so that the linker can resolve the undefined references in the source file. Try compiling the example with this

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -L/usr/local/lib xmltest.c -lxml2 -lm
```

Comment: I am getting this error (DemuxReportGenerator.cpp:129: undefined reference to `exsltRegisterAll') probably due to that I am using a newer version of the library: libxml2 2.9.13, libxslt 1.1.34. Or am I missing another library?